# Stylesheets Missing - Ruby On Rails Application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, .htaccess, stylesheet

I have a Ruby On Rails App. I am using Cpanel on centos 6.4 with phusion passenger.
My app runs fine with all the controllers and models working okk.
The issue is , I have Stylesheets, JS and Images in a folder named public (generally it is).
I have included all of them in my app but i get following error with all of them.

```
      No route matches "/javascripts/application.js" with {:method=>:get}
```

I am sure that all my files have correct path as previously when i use to use the app with mongrel, it use to work fine.

My .htaccess code is :-

```
    RailsBaseURI /
    PassengerAppRoot /home/crosstr/rails_apps/appname/public
```

My App specifications are :-

```
    Ruby 1.8.7-p352 
    Rails 2.3.5
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How are you adding the file? Works in local?

Comment: Yes it works in local.

Comment: I guess phusion is not taking the public folder where generally all the styles and js are kept.

Comment: I suppose you have `public/javascripts/application.js` file

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change this setting to true -

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in the environment/production.rb file. It's false by default in production.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

**Update**
The above is Rails 3 only, my mistake. 
`PassengerAppRoot` should point to the app root, and not public

Comment: I am using development mode. and i tried using this. this is not available in rails 2.3.5 , its a code for rails 3

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Your `PassengerAppRoot` should point to the app root, and not public though. What is your `DocumentRoot` set to?

Comment: I didnt understand Documentroot..?

Comment: I tried that and i removed public from PassengerAppRoot but then the application does not start.